# Regex starts with word but exclude if matches word exactly

Tags: regex

I want to take strings that start with *syslog* but but not syslog exactly

e.g:

- syslog = not match
- syslog.1 = match
- random = not match

So far, I have this to exclude syslog exactly:

```
(?!^syslog$)(^.*$)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a non whitespace char `\S` after matching syslog, and then match the rest of the line without using a lookahead.

```
^syslog\S.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBt0K8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
^syslog.+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/seElUP/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  syslog                   'syslog'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```